# UIDocumentPickerViewController dismisses parent view controller

Tags: xcode, wkwebview, uidocumentpickervc

I have a `WKWebView` in a view controller. When an user clicks on "Upload File" button (which is on the webpage shown), `UIDocumentPickerViewController` pops up. This is expected and totally neccessary but:

Whenever the user clicks on any button ("Upload Photo or Video", "Cancel"), the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` dismisses itself AND the parent view controller that it's in.

I have added a symbolic breakpoint for `[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]` and indeed saw that `-dismissViewController...` is called twice. After the first time it dismisses `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, after the second one – my parent view controller.

By the way, on the iPad there is no problem, probably because `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is presented as a popover.

Why is this happening and what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, were you able to resolve?

Comment: Ok, I was even able to reproduce this in a very simple sample project. I filed a radar with id # 29853806 for this, included [this sample project](https://db.tt/YaQtByqx3E) and [this video demo of the bug](https://db.tt/MXD5v8sdEP).

Comment: Hmm I have the opposite problem: the `presentingViewController` is dismissed when I tap outside the popover. 

Answer (score 2):

<s>Alright, I think I've found a way to fix this. WebKit is open source, and you can see the offending class is `WKFileUploadPanel`, specifically the [`_dismissDisplayAnimated:` method](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/ios/forms/WKFileUploadPanel.mm#L393) is called too aggressively inadvertently triggering dismissal of your view controller. In order to avoid this you need to block calls to `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` that come in from `WKFileUploadPanel`, which you can do by looking up the stack. Here's an implementation that resolves this.</s>

The solution mentioned above doesn't work because it relies on looking at the call stack symbols for a particular class which is obfuscated when running on a real device. Here's a different approach I took to resolve this:

1. Add a `weak` `UIDocumentMenuViewController` property to your modal view controller class.
2. Override `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` in your modal class to check and see if the view controller being presented is a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`, if so set it as the value for your weak property from step 1.
3. Override `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` to check if your weak property is `nil` yet, if it is not `nil` and your modal's `presentedViewController` is `nil` then it means that WebKit is trying to dismiss your modal when it shouldn't be. You can avoid calling `super` in that case, and continue calling it otherwise.

You can also swizzle `WKFileUploadPanel`'s [`_dismissDisplayAnimated:` method](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/ios/forms/WKFileUploadPanel.mm#L393) to be more careful about your own view controllers, but that comes with a significant amount of risk.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and finally managed to find a workaround.

In my view controller I override `dismiss` method to delete managed object if save button wasn't hit and that worked perfectly with `UIImagePickerController`.

As of my application uses `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, my managed object was deleted each time the `documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL)` was called because this causes a `presentingViewController.dismiss`.

So my solution is to check from the `presentingViewController` if the `presentedViewController` is `nil`or not to know if `dismiss` method was called by `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or not.

So here is my overriden `dismiss` method from my view controller.

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if self.presentedViewController == nil {
        // dismissed by the user
        myDocument.delete()
    } else {
        // dismissed by the UIDocumentPickerViewController
        // do nothing
    }
    super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue  , This happens while using document picker and occurs in iOS versions below 11.4  . Use the below code where ever you are using document picker. From what I have read from different forums there is an issue with document picker and it has been fixed in later versions of iOS .

Declare a weak property of document picker .

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIDocumentPickerViewController *_Nullable docPicker;
```

Then implement the view controller delegate methods :

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion
{
    if ([viewControllerToPresent isKindOfClass:[UIDocumentPickerViewController class]])
    {
        _docPicker = (UIDocumentPickerViewController*)viewControllerToPresent;
    }

    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}

- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag
                           completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    if (_docPicker != nil && self.presentedViewController == nil)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(working):

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```