# UIDocumentMenuViewController dismisses presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uidocumentmenuvc

I have a VC "A" that present VC "B" modally. B presents a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`
The `UIDocumentMenuDelegate` protocol is implemented in B.

As soon as `documentMenuWasCancelled(_ documentMenu:)` or `documentMenu(_:didPickDocumentPicker:)` gets called the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` of B gets called and i have no clue why.

Here's my code

```
func presentDocumentPicker() {
    let documentTypes = [
        kUTTypeCompositeContent as String,
        kUTTypePDF as String,
        "com.microsoft.word.doc",
        "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    ]
    let documentMenuViewController = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: documentTypes, in: .import)
    documentMenuViewController.delegate = self
    present(documentMenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Document Menu View Controller Delegate

func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print("did pick")
}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print("was cancelled")
}
```

As you can see I do nothing in the implemented delegate function. And still B gets dismissed. I don't get it.

Comment: Can you send more of the project to or at least the full ViewControllers you have there?

Comment: Actually right now i cannot reproduce it :D

Comment: there might be a issue of how you are presenting both controllers..

Comment: @lukwuerz, I am having the same problem here in a Simulator. As soon as I hit any action in the UIDocumentMenuViewController, view B dismisses. Were you able to get more information of this issue? Did it start to appear again? Was it on a simulator only or also on a real device?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL)` method which is called when you click on an action or when you cancel `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

I posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505488/6381503

Hope it helps.